# Filling an array with ints and strings using a class declaration

Tags: java, arrays, class

So I'm not sure what step I'm missing here in getting the array to print based on the established array that I initially declare. I know java has other ways to print arrays but I'm trying to keep the steps longer (rather than using Java shortcuts) so it's easier to apply the same methods to other languages. If someone could look at what I have and tell me what I'm missing I'd appreciate it.

UPDATE: I feel pretty dumb because it was a simple solution but now I'm dealing with another problem. I need the array to accept strings and ints so I made a class with public types word and number, but I'm not sure how to fill the array properly. I know I don't have numbers set to fill an array but if someone can help me figure out one I can do the other myself.

```
   package employeetotalhours;

 import java.util.ArrayList;

 public class employeetotalhours {  // main class declaration

public static class Table{          // sub class declaration
    public int number;      // establish input field values for ints
    public String word;     // establish input field values for strings
    Object array[];
}

public static void main(String[] args){ // main method  

Table[] table = new Table[9];

Table word = null;

table[0] = word;

ArrayList<Table> Table = new ArrayList<Table>();

Table.add(new Table());

 //         {{"Employee ","Su","M","T","W","T","F","Sa","Total"}, 
 //         {"EmpID 0       ","4 ","2","5","3","4","5","8 ", "0"}, 
 //         {"EmpID 1       ","1 ","7","8","4","3","3","4 ", "0"}, 
 //         {"EmpID 2       ","2 ","3","3","4","3","3","2 ", "0"}, 
 //         {"EmpID 3       ","3 ","3","3","7","3","4","1 ", "0"}, 
 //         {"EmpID 4       ","1 ","3","2","4","3","6","3 ", "0"}, 
 //         {"EmpID 5       ","5 ","3","4","4","6","3","4 ", "0"}, 
 //         {"EmpID 6       ","8 ","3","7","4","8","3","8 ", "0"}, 
 //         {"EmpID 7       ","2 ","6","3","5","9","2","7 ", "0"}};
    // all array data, multiple lines can be used as long as code is not closed with ;

    int rows = 9; // establish array row size

    int columns = 9; // establish array column size

    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(table[i] + " ");
        }
            System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your writing all the array elements to zero that is why it is re-initialized the values to 0.

```
for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) // loop to cycle through cells in array table
    for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        array[i][j] = 0;
```

Comment: Okay  so do I need to just remove that for loop then?

Comment: looking at it again I see it, feel dumb, I'll try it without that loop when I get the chance

Comment: @SirPapilonius Dont feel bad everyone are do the same :D

Answer (score 4):

Before the loop where you print all values, you have this loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) // loop to cycle through cells in array table
    for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        array[i][j] = 0;
```

In this loop you set every element of the array to 0.
So when you print the elements, everything is 0